# How do you find possible x, y values for the Knight's Tour Problem?

Tags: java, arrays, backtracking, chess, knights-tour

I was looking into the Knight's Tour Problem, where the solution is obtained when a chess knight piece moves to every square on a grid exactly once. However, upon looking at different solutions for the problem, I keep seeing a specific array of numbers:

```
int xMove[] = { 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2 };
int yMove[] = { 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1 };
```

Where exactly these integers are coming from? Is there a way that you can solve the problem without these specific integers, or are they essential to the problem? For reference, here is the full code I was looking at. (credit GeeksforGeeks)

```
// Java program for Knight Tour problem
class KnightTour {
    static int N = 8;
 
    /* A utility function to check if i,j are
       valid indexes for N*N chessboard */
    static boolean isSafe(int x, int y, int sol[][])
    {
        return (x >= 0 && x < N && y >= 0 && y < N
                && sol[x][y] == -1);
    }
 
    /* A utility function to print solution
       matrix sol[N][N] */
    static void printSolution(int sol[][])
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
                System.out.print(sol[x][y] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
 
    /* This function solves the Knight Tour problem
       using Backtracking.  This  function mainly
       uses solveKTUtil() to solve the problem. It
       returns false if no complete tour is possible,
       otherwise return true and prints the tour.
       Please note that there may be more than one
       solutions, this function prints one of the
       feasible solutions.  */
    static boolean solveKT()
    {
        int sol[][] = new int[8][8];
 
        /* Initialization of solution matrix */
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
                sol[x][y] = -1;
 
        /* xMove[] and yMove[] define next move of Knight.
           xMove[] is for next value of x coordinate
           yMove[] is for next value of y coordinate */

        int xMove[] = { 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2 };
        int yMove[] = { 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1 };
 
        // Since the Knight is initially at the first block
        sol[0][0] = 0;
 
        /* Start from 0,0 and explore all tours using
           solveKTUtil() */
        if (!solveKTUtil(0, 0, 1, sol, xMove, yMove)) {
            System.out.println("Solution does not exist");
            return false;
        }
        else
            printSolution(sol);
 
        return true;
    }
 
    /* A recursive utility function to solve Knight
       Tour problem */
    static boolean solveKTUtil(int x, int y, int movei,
                               int sol[][], int xMove[],
                               int yMove[])
    {
        int k, next_x, next_y;
        if (movei == N * N)
            return true;
 
        /* Try all next moves from the current coordinate
            x, y */
        for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            next_x = x + xMove[k];
            next_y = y + yMove[k];
            if (isSafe(next_x, next_y, sol)) {
                sol[next_x][next_y] = movei;
                if (solveKTUtil(next_x, next_y, movei + 1,
                                sol, xMove, yMove))
                    return true;
                else
                    sol[next_x][next_y]
                        = -1; // backtracking
            }
        }
 
        return false;
    }
 
    /* Driver Code */
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Function Call
        solveKT();
    }
}
// This code is contributed by Abhishek Shankhadhar
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simply an exhaustive list of all the moves a knight can make, relative to its current position.  That list is determined by the rules of chess (and the rectangular grid of a chessboard).

For example, the 0'th entries in both arrays mean "2 squares right and 1 square forward" - assuming x-coordinates increase left-to-right and y coordinates increase front-to-back.

You can determine the list for yourself by enumerating every possible combination of "two squares in one direction, and then one square at right-angles to it".